В чем заключается отличие SvelteKit от бэкенд-фреймворков
Я совсем новичок и пытаюсь определиться со стеком для своего проекта. Выбор пал на django+svelte. В момент падения выбора я предполагал, что svelteKit - нечто, упрощающее маршрутизацию между страницами фронтенда, и не более. Теперь же у меня есть ощущение, что svelteKit - нечто большее, и его можно использовать в качестве бэкенд-фреймворка. В итоге я запутался и у меня возникли следующие вопросы:

Чем отличается svelteKit от типичного "бэкенд" фреймворка?
Не избыточно ли использование svelteKit при наличии бэкенда на Django?


SvelteKit не может заменить полноценный бекенд, насколько я знаю, он ориентирован на SSR и SSG, он умеет обрабатывать маршрутизацию на стороне сервера и клиента, может выполнять предварительную загрузку данных, работать с API, но основная его задача — это все равно управление UI. Про избыточность, ну ит депендс уже от Ваших целей, если используете Django для написания API и Вам нужен SSR, то почему нет да и вообще, не вижу в чем может проявляться избыточность.
